# Can't import ore create X509Certificate2 object from byte array

Tags: x509certificate, x509certificate2

So I encountered a weird issue while trying importing `.pfx` file into `x509` object.

For some reason, I don't understand, trying opening, or generating new object, in this manner doesn't work.

```
  cert = new X509Certificate2();
  cert.Import(byte []);
```

```
  cert = new X509Certificate2(byte []);
```

The error I'm getting is:`'X509Certificate is immutable on this platform. Use the equivalent constructor instead.'`

I saw this issue: https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml/issues/9

the only way I could make it work is to give an explicit path to the `.pfx` path which worked.

That's not my intention, however.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What should work for you, is one of the constructor overload.

Use the other constructor of X509Certificate2 class which takes two params. First one is the byteArray and second one is the password string.

```
 byte[] certData;
 var memorystream = new MemoryStream();

 MyMethodToPopluateMemoryStream(memorystream);
 certData = memorystream.ToArray();

 cert = new X509Certificate2(certData,"CERT_PASSWORD");
```

This way you can avoid the deprecated Import method.
After few hours of struggle above code worked fine for me. I've tested this code on .net6 .

Happy Coding.